# 1.14 Theorem (Rudin's Complex analysis book)

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, measure-theory, supremum-and-infimum

$\textbf{1.14 Theorem}$ If $f_n: X \rightarrow [-\infty, +\infty]$ is measurable, for $n = 1, 2, 3,...,$ and $g= \sup_{n \geq 1} f_{n}$ and $h = \limsup_{n \to \infty} f_{n} $, then g and h are measurable.

$\textbf{Proof}$: $g^{-1}((\alpha, + \infty]) = \bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} f_{n}^{-1}((\alpha, + \infty])$. Hence Theorem 1.12(c) implies that $g$ is measureble. The same result holds of course with inf in place of sup, and since

$\underline{h = \inf_{k \geq 1} \{\sup_{i \geq k} f_{i}\}}$

it follows that $h$ is measurable.

Can someone explain me how this underlined implies that $h$ is measurable?

Comment: For the first underlined sentence, $g(x) > \alpha$ if and only if $f_n(x) > \alpha$ for some $n$. The second is the (or at least a) definition of $\limsup$.

Comment: The (currently) underlined formula says that $h$ is the inf of a sequence of functions, each of which is the sup of a sequence of measurable functions. The part of the proof  preceding the underlined formula says that measurability is preserved by both inf and sup of sequences.

Comment: @AndreasBlass So, must I apply the former result two times?

Comment: @JohnMars Right. Apply it first to the suprema of the original functions and then to the infimum of those suprema.